# "Вот оно что!" и "Вон оно что!"

Tags: семантика, частицы

***"Вот оно что!"*** и ***"Вон оно что!"***
Есть ли хоть малейшая смысловая, стилистическая или еще какая разница?

В других случаях все понятно. ***"Вот именно", "Вот тебе, бабушка, и Юрьев день!", "Вот, где собака зарыта!"*** или там ***"Вот дом, который построил Джек"*** не спутаешь с ***"С глаз долой, из сердца вон"*** или ***"Вон там по заре растянулся. Причудливый хор облаков"*** (Фет) - но это, возможно, другие значения.

(+)===
Я задал аналогичный вопрос на украинском форуме, но потом понял, что я и на русским-то не очень понимаю...

Answer (score 3):

Чаще используется выражение ***вот оно что***, **частотность** в Нацкорпусе  956:110.

Я полагаю, что существует некоторая разница **в семантических оттенках.**

Надо сравнить значение частиц ВОН и ВОТ.

**ВОН, частица.** 1. Указывает на лицо, предмет, действие и т.п. **в отдалении.**

**ВОТ, частица. 1**. Указывает на кого-, что-л., находящееся или происходящее перед глазами, **в непосредственной близости** или при рассказывании как бы перед глазами.

Мне кажется, что можно объяснить так:

1. ***Вот оно что!***

Теперь причина **ясна** (она перед нами, она ясно выражена).

2. ***Вон оно что!***

Теперь причина **начинает проясняться**,  видна хотя бы издалека, раньше ее вообще не было видно, даже трудно было предположить, в чем дело.

Comment: Sharon, еще до вашего ответа мне на украинском дали ссылку http://www.dialog-21.ru/digests/dialog2015/materials/pdf/KrylovaTV.pdf Я пока её изучу, потом ваше прокомментирую.